# React component not updating with its state, a 2d array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, multidimensional-array, react-hooks

My React component has a state variable which is a two dimensional array of characters representing a game board. The problem is that whenever I update the state the component is not re-rendering. I have verified that the state is indeed updating, but nothing changes on the screen. Here is the entire `Board` component (the `updateBoard` function is where the state is updated):

```
export const Board = () => {
    const [board, setBoard] = useState([
        ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        ['X', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    ]);

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const column = e.target.getAttribute('x');
        const row = board.findIndex((rowArr, index) => {
            return (rowArr[column] !== '' || index === board.length) ? true : false;
        }) - 1;

        updateBoard(row, column, 'X');
    };

    const updateBoard = (row, column, ch) => {
        setBoard(prev => {
            prev[row][column] = ch;
            return prev;
        })
    };

    return (
        <div id='board' onClick={handleClick}>
            {board.map((row, i) => {
                return row.map((ch, j) => <Slot ch={ch} y={i} x={j} />);
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I'm not sure what to do, the problem seems to be resulting from the fact that I'm using a 2d array. I have used a somewhat unconventional method of updating the state for this reason. I made sure to use the `setBoard` function and it's clear that the state is in fact updating. Still, nothing is re-rendering as it is supposed to.

Comment: You are using the same reference of an object and react can't detect a change. You have to create a new object each time

Comment: @Konrad I apologize but I'm not understanding what you're saying. Where am I using the same reference? Do you mean that `prev` is a reference to the same board and I need to make a copy of it?

Comment: Yes, that what I'm saying

Comment: @Konrad Thanks a lot, that was the issue. I had forgotten that arrays were reference types.